# how to make the buttons in the same line when im resizing the window

Tags: html, css

When im resizing the window and make it smaller the buttons going above each other
how can i make it in the same line

```css
.category {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
.category button {
    background-color: #3c3c3c;
    border-color: #3c3c3c;
    color: #ebebeb;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="category">
              <button>ALL</button>
              <button>SOFA</button>
              <button>CHAIR</button>
              <button>BED</button>
              <button>LAMP</button>
              <button>ACCESSORIES</button>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed a button in your HTML but if it's what you're searching for:

Using `display: flex;` and `overflow-x: visible;` you can achieve what you want even with a small screen. If you want to be able to scroll instead of just showing the overflow of your `div`, you can change `overflow-x` to `scroll` or `auto`.

```css
.category {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: visible;
    width: 80px;
}
.category button {
    background-color: #3c3c3c;
    border-color: #3c3c3c;
    color: #ebebeb;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="category">
  <button >Button 1</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to contain the buttons in the wrapper and keep the child only visible in that wrapper you can try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="category">
  <button >Button 1</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
  <button >Button 2</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.category {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
.category button {
    background-color: #3c3c3c;
    border-color: #3c3c3c;
    color: #ebebeb;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

This will keep your buttons in 50% width only. in overflow visible, it will take the full width and will not respect the width of the wrapper.